# Fill caps not working for curves

Tags: modeling, bezier-curves, bevel

Imported a profile that I applied to a curve but the "fill caps" doesnt work. What am I doing wrong?
[image: object data]
[image: fill caps not working]

Edit : one more image showing the bezier profile and including blend file.

[image: bezier profile]

[image]

Comment: can u share the blend file https://blend-exchange.com

Comment: @HarryMcKenzie just posted!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your curve is discontinued, there are some overlapping vertices and it looks like you can't fill between the vertices, probably because you've mixed a curve with a nurb? You can convert your curve to mesh, merge by distance, then convert back to curve and it will work. Or remove the nurb part and redo it entirely as a pure curve.

Comment: after an endless search...THANK YOU VERY MUCH!